# Redirect URL in python

Tags: django, python-2.7, browser, webbrowser-control

I'm breaking my head around this from couple of days now, here is the scenario.

I have written a class for our `internal sso` validation. When my `Django` app loads i'm calling a fucntion to validate the whether the sso user is a valid one or not, if no the page should redirect to the sso login page.

```
import webbrowser
@csrf_exempt
def Sso(request):
    #Initializing the sso class 
    ssoObj = sso(True)
    applicationURL = 'http://app.com'
    if not(ssoObj._isValidUser):
        redirectionUrl = ssoObj.GetRedirectionUrl(applicationURL)
        webbrowser.open(redirectionUrl)
    return HttpResponse("reached last line")
```

Note: default `ssoObj._isValidUser` will return `False`. `ssoObj.GetRedirectionUrl` function will return `SSO URL + "return=" + applicationURL`.

When ever the webbrowser.open is getting hit, its opening the redirected link `Mozilla`(might be my default browser,not sure). I want the redirect url to open at the same tab user is accessing the application url. How do i do this? any Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming this function executes upon user request, you will need to [set the response header](https://googl.com/#q=q=django+set+response+header) for the `Location` header for the desired URL.

Comment: If you don't mind, you can make the response a json response and then redirect via javascript.  You can do this by doing an ajax request to validate the sso and check the response whether it's valid or not.

Comment: @RieljunLiguid oh yeah, instead of understanding what goes wrong and why so it can be fixed, let's just add some useless complexity that will just leave the whole application opened to hackers. Great !

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yeah, right, thanks for your humble advice, have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is doubly wrong - `webbrowser.open(...)` tries to launch a brower on the system your code is running on,so you not only have an incorrect behaviour when running the django app locally, but it will also totally fail on production since it will try to open a brower on the *server* node - and will either fail with a an exception if your server system has no browser configured, or, worse, just hang until the browser is closed (which will never happen since there will be nobody to close it...) or the process is restarted.

The proper solution here is to return a response with a redirect status code and the url to redirect to. Django has both [the `HttpResponseRedirect` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) and [the even simpler `redirect()` shortcut function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect), so technically your code should look like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@csrf_exempt
def Sso(request):
    #Initializing the sso class 
    ssoObj = sso(True)
    applicationURL = 'http://app.com'
    if not(ssoObj._isValidUser):
        redirectionUrl = ssoObj.GetRedirectionUrl(applicationURL)
        return redirect(redirectionUrl)
    return HttpResponse("reached last line")
```

Now a couple caveats, side notes etc:

1/ Your class names should be CamelCased.

Your 'sso' class should be named `Sso` - or `SSOBackend` or something similar - not `sso`

2/ your function names should be all_lower.

Your `Sso` view should be named `sso` - but actually it should probably named after what it actually do, which is to validate wether your user has been authenticated against your SSO server and redirect him if not

3/ Your variables and attributes names should be all_lower too.

ssoObj => sso_obj

applicationURL => application_url

GetRedirectionUrl => get_redirection_url

_isValidUser => _is_valid_user

3/ a leading underscore denotes a private attribute

So either `_is_valid_user` should be made public by renaming it `is_valid_user` or the the class has some other public way to give you this information and which you should be using.

And last but not least, quite on the contrary:

4/ **[You should use `django.contrib.auth` features and provide your own authentification backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/) instead of reinventing the proverbial SquaredWheel(tm)**

Comment: Thank you for the the reply and your time on this request. I have already tried `return redirect(redirectionUrl)` but it returns `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://sso/login.php?return=http://app:80/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://app:80' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: were did you mention that you were calling this view from an ajax request?

Comment: i tried adding `corsheaders`, but still the same issue. ajax call is provided below.

 `$.ajax(
 {
  url: 'sso/',
  method:'POST',
  success: function(response){
   console.log(response)
  }
 });`

Comment: in other words, just run pylint on your code and follow the instructions in output